# Optimal figures arrangement on a square matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem and cannot think of how:

We have a set of figures (line, square, 'plus' etc.) and they are initially placed on a matrix, so that some of them overlap. We are looking for least number of moves so that figures don't overlap. Figures don't move diagonally, only vertically and horizontally.

Thanks

Comment: Recommend you reading the `faq` page of the site.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: I doubt your comment helps the OP. If you think there is a problem with the question, why don't you suggest how the question could be improved instead?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier for us to help you if you describe how you approached the problem so for. Also, what do you consider a 'move'? Can you give some small examples with the expected answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) solution:

- Assume an ([implicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph)) graph consisting of vertices that each represent a unique location of
  all figures in the matrix and where edges represent legal moves of a single
  figure (up/down/left/right which do not cause the figure to move outside the matrix).
- Perform a breadth-first search through this graph by adding the node representing the initial figure configuration to the BFS queue marked as unvisited.
- For each unvisited node in the queue check if it is overlap-free, if it is you are done, if it is not mark it as visited and add its neighbors (all possible one-step moves of all figures from that configuration) to the end of the BFS queue. You can use a HashSet to store which nodes (unique configurations of figure locations) you have visited since identical configurations can be reached through different move sequences.
- If the BFS queue becomes empty there is no solution as you have checked all possible figure configurations.